# SQL/mariadb Select with IN() over mutiple columns in the same order

Tags: sql, mariadb

I need a syntax in sql which returns a result in the same order as given in the IN() field.
The problem is that the primary key consists of two keys.

So the following does not apply:

```
SELECT * FROM table where id IN (4,5,6) ORDER BY FIELD (id,4,5,6);
```

my table:

```
primary(column 1+2)   column 3   column 4   cloumn 5......
    hash | num      |          |          |
```

Pseudo code for understanding would look like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE (hash,num) IN (["fjdigjhu",5],["fgfjhgaa",2],...) ORDER BY FIELD ([hash,num],["fjdigjhu",5],["fgfjhgaa",2],...);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest a derived table:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM table t JOIN
     (SELECT 1 as ord, 'fjdigjhu' as hash, 5 as num UNION ALL
      SELECT 2 as ord, 'fgfjhgaa' as hash, 5 as num UNION ALL
      . . . 
     ) x
     USING (hash, num)
ORDER BY x.ord;
```

Comment: This works! Hope it is faster than using single queries for this task.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `case..when` as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM table where (hash,num) IN (["fjdigjhu",5],["fgfjhgaa",2],...)
 ORDER BY case when (hash,num) IN (["fjdigjhu",5]) then 1
               when (hash,num) IN (["fgfjhgaa",2]) then 2
               .....
          end;
```

Comment: no, there is no id field, the table has the form (hash, num , cloumn3, column4...) while hash+num builds the primary key or the combination I'm looking for.

Comment: ok, but this is not even valid sql syntax. (at least not for mariadb) that was the reason, why I wrote "pseudo code". The brackets [ and ] seem to be the problem. also illegal parameter for IN #4078

Comment: Obviously, It is not valid syntax. I was just giving you idea of how to do it